# Get position of MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, position

MySQL Query that lists all Records ordered by their points and rank. But now, how do I get special columns from a name?

Query:

```
    SET @a=0; 
    SELECT (@a:=@a+1) as Rank, `player`, `points`, `id` FROM `score` 
    ORDER BY `points` DESC (WHERE player='example');
```

Thanks for helping. :)

I'm using Java.

Comment: Why make the poor database count this up for you.  Whatever loop you use to paint it to the browser is more than capable of coming up with the rank.  Even wrapping the results in a `<OL>` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT (@a:=@a+1) as Rank, `player`, `points`, `id` 
  FROM `score` 
  CROSS JOIN (select @a := 0) ta
  ORDER BY `points` DESC
) tmp
WHERE player='example'
```

Comment: It says "NULL" at Rank

Comment: I added the variable into the query

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE` clause before `ORDER BY` like this-

```
SET @a=0; 
SELECT (@a:=@a+1) as Rank, `player`, `points`, `id` FROM `score` 
WHERE player='example' ORDER BY `points` DESC;
```